# 2 Forms in a django template using cookiecutter-django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, cookiecutter-django

I'm creating 2 forms on one template in cookiecutter-django. I have both forms working on a normal django project but when I migrated them to cookiecutter-django, the forms did not work on the user_detail template.

This is the forms.py

```
class NarrateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Narrate
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
        ]
        exclude = ('status',)


class TranslateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Translate
        fields = [
            'title',
            'body',
        ]
        exclude = ('status',)
```

These are the views.py of forms that I have:

```
class TranslateFormView(FormView):
    form_class = TranslateForm
    template_name = 'user_detail.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        add_translation = self.form_class(request.POST)
        add_narration = NarrateForm()
        if add_translation.is_valid():
            add_translation.save()
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    success=True
                )
            )
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    add_translation=add_translation,
                )
            )

class NarrateFormView(FormView):
    form_class = NarrateForm
    template_name = 'users/user_detail.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        add_narration = self.form_class(request.POST)
        add_translation = TranslateForm()
        if add_narration.is_valid():
            add_narration.save()
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    success=True
                )
            )
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(
                    add_narration=add_narration,
                )
            )
```

Now this is the view of the user_details from cookiecutter-django

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = User
    slug_field = "username"
    slug_url_kwarg = "username"


user_detail_view = UserDetailView.as_view()
```

This is the code on the template which works on the old django project

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_narration }}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Narration">Submit Narration</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="#">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_translation }}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Narration">Submit Narration</button>
</form>
```

I've been trying to make this work for more than 2 hours already and had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be creating a basic form (extend django.forms.Form) in the forms.py file, manually creating the fields and the modela later on in the views.py file.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Could I include both the forms on the UserDetailView since that's the view of where I want those 2 forms?

Comment: Yes, you can just initialize them in UserDetailViee.get_context_data() and output them in one <form> with <form action=“save_method”>

Answer (score 1):

give the submit inputs different names as shown here

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_narration }}
    <button type="submit" name="narrationsubmit" value="Send Narration">Submit Narration</button>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="#">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_translation }}
    <button type="submit" name="transaltionsubmit" value="Send Narration">Submit Narration</button>
</form>
```

Then  handle them as below in your view.

```
def handleforms(request):
    if request.method =="POST" and "narrationsubmit" in request.post:
        //process
    elif request.method =="POST" and "transaltionsubmit" in request.post:
        //process
```

NB: this is for a function based view. format it for a CBV